# Intentionally returning None instead of object

Tags: python, python-typing

Suppose I have two simple classes:

```py
@dataclass
class Item():
  Name: str
  Valie: float

class Registry():
  items = []
  
  def __init__(self):
    # load some items from external source, etc

  """ find an element in an array or return None """
  def find(self, name: str) -> Item:
    for i in self.Items:
      if i.Name = name: # items are unique, 
         return i
    return None # ignore type
```

Without this `#ignore type` got warning `Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to return type "Item"`. Ok, I understand why. But is this the right approach or is there a better more "pythonic" way to solve this problem? i.e. returns nothing if it is not in the list.

On the "other side" is something like:

```py
item = registry.find(name)
if item != None:
  doSomething()
```

Comment: The other alternative is to raise an exception instead of returning `None`. (Functions that raise exceptions don't return in the normal sense, so you wouldn't have to change the return type.)

Comment: If you are going to do this, instead of `# ignore type`, why don't you just type annotate the return value correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type hint to `Optional[Item]` which allows either `Item` or `None` (equivalent to `Item | None`).

```py
from typing import Optional

def find(self, name: str) -> Optional[Item]:
```

See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional